# matplotlib - faster frame rate?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have written a simple script based on the code from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/02/16/animating-the-lorentz-system-in-3d/)

I just need to display dots, no lines needed.

The script below displays the dots correctly but I would like to see the dots move much faster, in a configurable manner at a frame rate of let's say 30fps.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import cnames
from matplotlib import animation

NbOfObjects = 3

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection='3d')
ax.axis('on')

ax.set_xlim((-1.5, 1.5))
ax.set_ylim((-1.5, 1.5))
ax.set_zlim((0, 1.5))

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')

# set point-of-view: specified by (altitude degrees, azimuth degrees)
ax.view_init(30, 30)

# choose a different color for each trajectory
colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, NbOfObjects))

# set up points
pts = sum([ax.plot([], [], [], 'o', c=c)
           for c in colors], [])

data = [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]]


# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    for pt in pts:
        pt.set_data([], [])
        pt.set_3d_properties([])

    return pts


def animate(i):

    print "i: ", i

    for pt, positon in zip (pts, data[i]):

        x = positon[0]
        y = positon[1]
        z = positon[2]

        pt.set_data(x, y)
        pt.set_3d_properties(z)

    fig.canvas.draw()

    return  pts

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1, frames=len(data), blit=True, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

1. How does the display of the frames on the screen relate to the "interval" parameter in `animation.FuncAnimation`? (I can't get it to display the 50 frames in less than 5 secs)
2. Is this design the best way to deal with a large number of dots (10+) at potentially 30fps over a long duration? ("data" would be pretty big for a 1h duration).

I'm still studying the various examples but none show a simple 3D animated scatter plot.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably do better to plot all the points in one call, passing an array of colors as the `c=` argument rather than an object. Although I guess with only 3 points in each frame, it probably makes little difference

Comment: I think `blit=True` makes `fig.canvas.draw()` unecessary

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I haven't made exact measurements yet but I'm confident that 30 fps are now achievable . This is awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation):

   > kwargs include `repeat`, `repeat_delay`, and `interval`: `interval` draws a new frame **every `interval` milliseconds**. `repeat` controls whether the animation should repeat when the sequence of frames is completed. `repeat_delay` optionally adds a delay in milliseconds before repeating the animation.

   However, this only sets an upper bound on the frame rate - if it takes too long to draw a frame, then you'll see a slower frame rate
2. If you have a larger number of dots, you'll want to do something like:

   ```
   data = np.array(data)

   # in init, get a single mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D object
   # the comma is important!
   pts, = ax.plot([], [], [], 'o', c=colors)

   # in update()
   pts.set_data(data[i,:,0], data[i,:,1])
   pts.set_3d_properties(data[i,:,2])
   ```

   So that you can eliminate the for loop

Comment: 2/ I get the importance of the comma now (assign the first element of the list to pts). Anyway, I think I get your idea... I have modified the 2 functions as per your suggestion, however in update() I now get **"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_data'** which makes sense since pts is a list.
I'm not sure how to do this without using a(nother) "for" loop. I'll try to find some info in the doc. Thx.

Comment: `pts` is a Line3D object on my machine... Or does the first line of that comment supercede the rest of it>

Comment: You're right, I've defined pts as "pts, = ax.plot([], [], [], 'o')" and the above code now works. I do get around 20% performance increase using this suggestion. I've also noticed a big difference between Windows and OS X, the script runs much faster on Windows. As for my first question, it was malformulated... It seems that animate() is called a few times per seconds - way less than "interval". I do not understand how a new frame can be drawn every 30 ms for instance when the function is called every 100 ms for example.

Comment: `animate` will be called after whichever comes _last_: the period has elapsed, or the previous rerender has finished. Even if you speed up `animate`, redrawing the figure takes time